# Resize to Inches Using ImageMagick Convert?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using the following command to resize all the images in a folder:

```
convert folder\*.png" -format jpg -resize 1573 -quality 70 -strip -density 72 -interlace Plane -set filename:fname %t-1 +adjoin "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\New folder\%[filename:fname].jpg"
```

It works, but instead of resizing to 1,573 pixels, I'd like to resize to 8.5 inches in width and 11 inches in height. How can I do that using ImageMagick Convert?

Comment: Inches is only important when you print and depends upon the dimensions and the density. If you have 1573 and want 8.5 in you would need to set the density to 1573/8.5=185 pixels/in rather than 72 pixels/in (dpi)

Answer (score 0):

The "print size" of an image is the combination of its size in pixels and it print resolution, the matter being just metadata:

```
print size (inches) = size in pixels ÷ print resolution (in PPI)
```

So to change your image to 8.5×11 inches you can just change the resolution:

```
Necessary resolution = 1513 pixels ÷ 11 inches = 138PPI
```

The usual tool to edit metadata is ExifTool:

```
exiftool -xresolution=138 -yresolution=138 -v2 your_image.jpg
```

This of course assumes that your image is already in the 11 ÷ 8.5 aspect ratio. Otherwise you compute different X and Y print resolutions or first crop the image to achieve the proper aspect ratio.

Also, watch out for low resolution values. If you have text or sharp lines in the image (logo, CGI) 150PPI is on the low side...